# How to import esm modules with NodeJS 13, and Typescript 3.8?

Tags: node.js, typescript, import, module

I have a problem with some imports in NodeJS. I want to use the new features of Typescript 3.8, like private fields : #myPrivateField

I don't know how to correctly import the module "typescript" in my class. I tried many options, but impossible to solve my problem.

My files :

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && node --experimental-modules --es-module-specifier-resolution=node main.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^13.13.2",
    "app-root-path": "^3.0.0",
    "fs-extra": "^9.0.0",
    "tsutils": "^3.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "ESNext",
      "es2016",
      "dom",
      "es5"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

**main.ts**

```
// import ts = require("typescript");
import * as ts from "typescript";

export class Main {

    node: ts.Node;
    #test = 'zzz';

    constructor() {}

    process(): void {
        ts.forEachChild(this.node, function cb() {
        });
        console.log('#test', this.#test);
    }
}

const main = new Main();
main.process();
```

With this code, when I run `npm run start`, I have the error `TypeError: ts.forEachChild is not a function`

Without the line with `ts.forEachClid()` it logs correctly the value of the private field #test.

If I try to replace `import * as ts from "typescript";` by `import ts = require("typescript");`, I have the error `TS1202: Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript modules. Consider using 'import * as ns from "mod"', 'import {a} from "mod"', 'import d from "mod"', or another module format instead`

Of course, I tried many changes in tsconfig.json and in package.json (with `"type" = "module"), but impossible to solve this problem.

I even tried to replace `"module": "esnext"` by `"module": "commonjs"`, but I have an error `exports is not defined`.

Remark :
This is not specific to the module "typescript". I have the same problem with other modules like "fs-extra", which are making exports in a different way than most of classic NodeJS modules.

For example, the module "typescript" exports with `export = ts`.

I found this reference too, but it didn't help me a lot : 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

My nodeJs version is 13.3.0 and my typescript version is 3.8.3
Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't know `typescript` but I think your issue is not about import. As you see `ts.Node` was resolved, then you import `typescript` correctly. According to [TypeScript doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#ecmascript-private-fields), you should define private fields like this: `#test: string;` and initial it in the constructor: `constructor() { this.#test = 'zzz'; }`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. But no, in Typescript you can declare and initialize properties outside the constructor. Typescript will just transpile them in javascript by setting their value inside the javascript constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, the good response was : you need `commonjs` and `es2018` to be able to use the typescript #privateFields in a node module.

Here is the correct tsconfig.json to use :

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es2018",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "lib": [
            "es2018",
            "dom"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ESM Modules are still in experimental mode, there are a lot of modules that do not support it, e.g. uses `module.exports` (CommonJS) instead of `export` (ESM).

Your best choice here is to use `commonjs` module and run `node` without any flags. Also, `type` of the package in `package.json` must be `commonjs` as well.

---

Answering your question "How to import ESM module"... In case, module **does support** ESM modules, you can just use `import` as you usually do:

```
import { something } from './something';
```

---

**UPD:** as OP author mentioned, for private fields to work, there is must be set a target `es2018`. The reasoning behind this is that private fields is not a part from ES2015 specification and you need to upgrade to the minimal supported target to do that.

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "module": "commonjs",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "target": "es2018"
}
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for your reply ! You're right, the best option is to use `commonjs`, but you need too to use `es2018` to avoid other bugs. I wrote the correct answer in the below post. Thanks for your help !

Comment: I've updated the answer to explain the reasoning why you need to upgrade your target. If everything worked out for you, feel free to accept it as an answer to your question. Thanks!